# Using preventDefault in checkbox click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, click, preventdefault

I have a checkbox and the requirement is that when the user clicks it, instead of immediately changing its state, a modal window should pop up asking them a yes/no question. Depending on their answer, the checkbox should either become checked or remain unchecked.

I thought that this requirement should be handled using `Event.preventDefault()` but when I tried to do it I discovered that when I exit the event handler, the checkbox is reverted to its original state, regardless of my programmatic attempts to set the state in the handler.

```js
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop("checked", confirm("Confirm to check the checkbox"));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="checkbox">Click me</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
</form>
```

So how can I implement the required behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you called `preventDefault()` at all. You don't need it in this case as the `checked` state is entirely dependant on the outcome of the `confirm()` call.

Also note that you should use the `change` event, not `click`, when dealing with checkboxes. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function(e) {
    $(this).prop("checked", confirm("Confirm to check the checkbox"));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="checkbox">Click me</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
</form>
```